# Dynamically load XAML

Tags: gridview, xamlparseexception

I have a series of dynamically created GridViews that I load. Everything works fine except when the row details are expanded I get an error "Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:EMR.Controls.HPI}HPIDialogButton'. The namespace EMR.Controls.HPI is in the executing assembly and I can use the exact same XAML other places and it works without problems. If I comment out the line 'hpi:HPIDialogButton...' then the row details expand without problems.

It seems at the loading point there is some connection missing that is created for you if you do things directly.

```
   private RadGridView BuildSectionGrid()
    {
      //This is defined here until a better solution is found
      string XAML = @"
          <my:RadGridView IsReadOnly=""False"">
            <my:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewToggleRowDetailsColumn />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header=""Selected"" DataMemberBinding=""{Binding IsSelected}"" IsReadOnly=""False""/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header=""Definition"" DataMemberBinding=""{Binding Definition}"" IsReadOnly=""True""/>
            </my:RadGridView.Columns>

            <my:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel Margin=""10"">
                        <Label Content=""Progress Note:"" DockPanel.Dock=""Left""/>
                        <hpi:HPIDialogButton Margin=""5 0 0 0"" DockPanel.Dock=""Right"" HPIText=""{Binding ElementName=NoteItemTextBox, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}""/>
                        <TextBox Name=""NoteItemTextBox"" Margin=""5 0 0 0"" DockPanel.Dock=""Left"" AcceptsReturn=""True"" TextWrapping=""Wrap"" Height=""100"" Text=""{Binding ProgressNote}""/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </my:RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </my:RadGridView>
";


      //Load the XAML in again
      ParserContext Context = new ParserContext();
      Context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
      Context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
      Context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
      Context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("telerik", "http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation");
      Context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("hpi", "clr-namespace:EMR.Controls.HPI");
      Context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("my", "clr-namespace:EMR.Shared.Controls.WPF;assembly=EMR.Shared.Controls.WPF");
      return (RadGridView)XamlReader.Parse(XAML, Context);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to specify assembly in all your xmlns (you miss it in one):

Context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("hpi", "clr-namespace:EMR.Controls.HPI;assembly=EMR.Controls.HPI");